# Running K_Means Clustering Algo and Getting Weird Results

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running the code below.

```
from pylab import plot,show
from numpy import vstack,array
from numpy.random import rand
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as dr
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\in_path\\raw_data.csv')
print('done!')

df = df[:100000]
df = df.fillna(0)

dataset = df[['AcctNo', 'PriceBin', 'CouponBin', 'RatingScore', 'Term', 'LRMScore', 'Spread']].copy() # 'Rating' # 'HQLACategoryOne'

#format the data as a numpy array to feed into the K-Means algorithm
data = np.asarray([np.asarray(dataset['Spread']),np.asarray(dataset['Score'])]).T

centroids,_ = kmeans(data,500)
# assign each sample to a cluster
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)

# some plotting using numpy's logical indexing
plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], c=idx, s=50, cmap='viridis')
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], c='red', s=200, alpha=0.5)

details = [(name,cluster) for name, cluster in zip(dataset.Cusip,idx)]
for detail in details:
    print(detail)

details_df = pd.DataFrame(details)
details_df.columns = ['AccountNo','ClusterID']
finalDF = pd.merge(dataset, details_df, left_index=False, right_index=False, how='inner')

finalDF.to_csv('C:\\out_path\\test.csv')
```

I am looking at 'Spread' relative to 'Score'.  These two features are just slightly positively correlated; around 14%.  I don't know if that's the problem or not, but I thought the clustering would be done based on the 'Spread' and 'Score', but my ClusterIDs don't seem to be related to either variable.  Did I do something wrong?  Did I miss something?

Finally, I am getting these results (just a small sample).

```
AcctNo      PriceBin    CouponBin   RatingScore Term    Score   Spread  ClusterID
A85771075   0           5           0           30      9.75    0.13    3
A16898795   0           7           0           30      9.75    0.13    3
A87632163   0           5           0           30      9.75    0.06    7
A32073695   0           5           0           30      9.75    0.06    7
A05966021   -1          2           0           29      9.75    0.12    2
A38865245   0           4           0           30      9.75    0.07    10
A17800838   0           3           0           30      9.75    0.06    7
A19974047   0           6           0           15      9.75    0.16    3
A93145719   0           6           0           15      9.75    0.16    3
A32581133   0           6           0           15      9.75    0.16    3
A56322331   0           6           0           15      9.75    0.16    3
A67851213   0           6           0           15      9.75    0.16    3
A51232438   0           6           0           15      9.75    0.16    3
```

Comment: In the sample data you posted, the clusters seem to be exactly correlated to ranges of `Spread` w.r.t. the single included value of `Score`, (as in, there's one cluster ID for each set of values) so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I put the results in Excel and filtered on 9.75.  So, if ClusterID = 3 is based on Score = 9.75 and Spread = .13, why is ClusterID = 10 based on Score = 9.75 and Spread = .07.  I read about clustering before hacking this code together.  I think it's doing what it is supposed to do, but it's a little hard to interpret the results.

Comment: Are you concerned that the cluster label doesn't seem linearly related to the data? Because the labels are just that: Labels for the clusters, not some linear combination of the clusters. If you want something linearly interpretable, then perhaps a supervised algorithm might be a better fit

Comment: I guess it was just a little too perfect.  It makes sense now.  I just had to mull it over a bit.  Thanks for sharing your thoughts.